# How to use classes from two different packages in a Spring Boot test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

## My Setting:

1. Java 20
2. Spring Boot 3.0.7

## Original setup

1. Classes `Provider`, `Manager`, and `Client` in `my.com.app.entities` package
2. Class `Client` references `Provider` and `Manager`
3. Spring Boot application class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "my.com")
public class AppApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          // many things
    }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*").exposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Application context loads with no problem during tests. Integration tests run perfectly.

## New setup

1. Due to code reorganization, classes `Provider` and `Manager` were moved to package `my.com.core.entities` (at this time, in the same project)
2. Class `Client` continues in package `my.com.app.entities`, with references to `Provider` and `Manager`

No compile errors (refactorer took care of reference updates), but after the above refactoring, integration tests don't run anymore. For each test there is an exception stack like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3294102e testClass = my.com.app.ClientRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [my.com.app.AppApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test-integration"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@6c4906d3, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4d1bf319, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@17bffc17, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@55cb6996, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4b520ea8, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@91305a8a], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Association 'my.com.app.entity.Client.provider' targets an unknown entity named 'my.com.core.Provider'
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'my.com.app.entity.Client.provider' targets an unknown entity named 'my.com.core.Provider'
```

## My expectation

I expected that the annotation in AppApplication class informing to scan from `my.com` and below would include classes `my.com.core.entities.Provider` and `my.com.core.entities.Manager`, but it didn't.

My tests have the following custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@ActiveProfiles("test-integration")
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(CleanUpExtension.class)
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

## What I tried

I tried to add the following configuration class in `my.com.core.config`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CoreConfig {
}
```

Then I updated my test annotation to:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@ActiveProfiles("test-integration")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AppApplication.class, CoreConfig.class})
@ExtendWith(CleanUpExtension.class)
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

## Results

Problem continues just the same.

What Am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you change anything about your entities during the refactor other than their package? Can it be that the refactor modified something else as well? Looks like a mapping issue; could you include the corresponding parts from the entities?

Comment: Git history shows that the only change in the  `Client` class is  at the very first line, which means, the only difference is the package name stated for the class and its location in the project structure. For other classes, the change is the import for `Provider` and `Manager` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, however I'm no sure why it was necessary. My `@IntegrationTest` annotation looked originaly like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@ActiveProfiles("test-integration")
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(CleanUpExtension.class)
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

I had to improve it to declare where to look for entities, by adding the `@EntityScan` annotation. Now my `@IntegrationTest` annotation declaration looks like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@ActiveProfiles("test-integration")
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(CleanUpExtension.class)
@EntityScan({"my.com.core.entities", "my.com.app.entities"}) // This is the fix!
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

That's it!